# How to make a library method call asynchronous?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am calling a library method that is synchronous. I'd like to use the new `async` and `await` features, but I'm not sure how since the library does not support asyncronity (does not return a task).

Is there a way to do it or do I need to build a wrapper that does *what exactly*?

Comment: What exactly is this method performing synchronously? Tasks are also .net 4.0.

Comment: If you really want to use async/await, you'd need to write a wrapper class that has a method marked async, which calls your library method.

Comment: Why not implement your own `BeginXXX` `EndXXX` methods using the threading API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run synchronous code in a background thread by calling it inside of `Task.Run`.

Comment: True, but be sure to take [the official recommendations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) into consideration.

Comment: [`Task.Run`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194919(v=vs.110)) is available only for .NET Framework 4.5

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

new Task<bool>(() =>
{
    // Do something
    return true;
}).Start();
```